Method '.ListRows' of object 'ListObject' failing
I am trying to iterate over the rows of an Excel table (ListObject) in VBA, with a simple For Each loop, right after iterating once through the same table in the same fashion :
With Sheet3.ListObjects("Contractuels")
    For Each r In .ListRows
        dict.Add Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("mail_ouvert").Range).Value, Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("CMI / IPR").Range).Value
    Next r
    Call ImportPQ
    Call FormatCTENTable
    For Each ro In .ListRows
        For Each i In dict.Items
            If i.Key = Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("mail_ouvert").Range).Value Then
                Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("CMI / IPR").Range).Value = i.Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next ro
End With

I get an error over the second iteration, which reads:
"Run-time error '-721329648 (d5016210)' :
Method 'ListRows' of object 'ListObject' failed"

I didn't know whether the problem was that I'd originally re-used the For Each r in .ListRows from above, for the second iteration, so I changed the variable r to ro. Same error.
This has me stumped, and I cannot even think of what to do to try and go around the problem, so any help will be greatly appreciated...

Do your calls to ImportPQ or FormatCTENTable modify the data at all? Does the Contractuels ListObject still exist after you run those routines? In other words, if you take out those 2 Call lines, does it still error?

@braX : Good point! No, I don't get the error, but I still have a table called "Contractuels" on Sheet3 in the workbook. Would it be because ImportPQ deletes the table, and then recreates another one (called the same way)? So the Withactually can't find the original table it was manipulating? I'll try it with another With...

That would explain it. Use a separate With statement for each loop.

Yup, it works! Thanks @braX!!

You could probably get away with one With statement if you recreated the code that deletes the ListObject to instead just delete the rows in it, and then recreate just the new rows.

A Dictionary Lookup with Update After Power Query Refresh

Although the following fixes the issue, I didn't figure it out. braX did it in the comments.

Looping through the cells is slow but using Intersect is additionally slowing down your operation. Instead, before the loop, you could retrieve the columns with...
Dim k As Long: k = .ListColumns("mail_ouvert").Index`
Dim v As Long: v = .ListColumns("CMI / IPR").Index`

... and use
r.Range.Cells(k).Value
r.Range.Cells(v).Value


Also, you are writing the data to the dictionary to avoid an inner loop. Instead of the For Each i... loop, check for existence using the following:
Dim kValue As Variant

kValue = r.Range.Cells(k).Value
If dict.Exists(kValue) Then
    r.Range.Cells(v).Value = dict(kValue)
End If


BTW, you can safely use the same r variable in both loops.


Call
Sub UpdateContractuels()
    UpdateTableColumns Sheet3, "Contractuels", "mail_ouvert", "CMI / IPR"
End Sub

Main
Sub UpdateTableColumns( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal TableName As String, _
        ByVal KeyColumnTitle As String, _
        ByVal ValueColumnTitle As String)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = TableColumnsToDictionary( _
        ws, TableName, KeyColumnTitle, ValueColumnTitle)
    
    ImportPQ
    FormatCTENTable
        
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    TableColumnsUpdateFromDictionary _
        ws, TableName, KeyColumnTitle, ValueColumnTitle, dict

    MsgBox "Table """ & TableName & """ updated.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help
Function TableColumnsToDictionary( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal TableName As String, _
    ByVal KeyColumnTitle As String, _
    ByVal ValueColumnTitle As String) _
As Object

    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = lo.ListRows.Count
    If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' empty table
    
    Dim kData() As Variant:
    kData = GetTableSingleColumnRange(lo, KeyColumnTitle)
    Dim vData() As Variant:
    vData = GetTableSingleColumnRange(lo, ValueColumnTitle)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim kValue As Variant, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        kValue = kData(r, 1)
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(kValue) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(kValue) Then
                dict.Add kValue, vData(r, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set TableColumnsToDictionary = dict

End Function

Sub TableColumnsUpdateFromDictionary( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal TableName As String, _
        ByVal KeyColumnTitle As String, _
        ByVal ValueColumnTitle As String, _
        ByVal dict As Object)

    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = lo.ListRows.Count
    If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' empty table
    
    Dim kData() As Variant:
    kData = GetTableSingleColumnRange(lo, KeyColumnTitle)
    Dim vData() As Variant
    vData = GetTableSingleColumnRange(lo, ValueColumnTitle)
    
    Dim kValue As Variant, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        kValue = kData(r, 1)
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(kValue) Then
            If dict.Exists(kValue) Then
                vData(r, 1) = dict(kValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    lo.ListColumns(ValueColumnTitle).DataBodyRange.Value = vData

End Sub

Function GetTableSingleColumnRange( _
    ByVal lo As ListObject, _
    ByVal ColumnTitle As String) _
As Variant
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = lo.ListRows.Count
    If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = lo.ListColumns(ColumnTitle).DataBodyRange.Value
        GetTableSingleColumnRange = Data
    Else
        GetTableSingleColumnRange = _
            lo.ListColumns(ColumnTitle).DataBodyRange.Value
    End If
End Function

Function IsNoErrorNoBlank(ByVal Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsError(Value) Then Exit Function
    If Len(Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
    IsNoErrorNoBlank = True
End Function


Wow! Thanks a million @VBasic2008! I am definitely going to implement all of this (and THANK YOU for the trick to avoid Application.Intersect! I couldn't believe I had to write such cumbersome code each time I wanted to designate a cell!)

As @braX suggested in the comments, one of the subs (ImportPQ) indeed deleted and re-created the table I was working with, albeit on the same sheet, with the same name. It doesn't matter to VBA: the With statement was manipulating another ListObject (which had therefore been deleted), so it threw an error. The solution is thus to use two With statements, so that the new table can be stored in memory for further manipulation.
Here's the updated code:
With Sheet3.ListObjects("Contractuels")
    For Each r In .ListRows
        dict.Add Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("mail_ouvert").Range).Value, Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("CMI / IPR").Range).Value
    Next r
End With
Call ImportPQ
Call FormatCTENTable
With Sheet3.ListObjects("Contractuels")
    For Each ro In .ListRows
        For Each i In dict.Items
            If i.Key = Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("mail_ouvert").Range).Value Then
                Application.Intersect(r.Range, .ListColumns("CMI / IPR").Range).Value = i.Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next ro
End With

Again, thanks @braX!

Why do you assign value to ro if it is never used? Is it a typo?
